# Trying to create a webhook on Autodesk where the callbackUrl is an Appian web API

Tags: autodesk, appian

I'm trying to post a webhook on Autodesk which callbackurl is an Appian web API. The problem I have, I can't expose any Appian service without authentication, and in the post method I don't see any option where I can write an API-key or something similar, only the callbackurl.

Does Autodesk Webhook API have any element or method where I can send the Appian API-Key?
Is there any other option? How is managed with others BPMs?

Comment: Quick check, is it possible to use the token to verify the callback as Webhooks provided at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/how-to-verify-payload-signature/ ? or has to be your own authentication?

Comment: I need to use my own authentication, I think I'm going to use an APIM to do this case

Comment: Hi Angel, Can I know what the APIM you are referring to? API Management?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this can be achieved with your own Authentication, but looks some feedback I can forward to our APS Webhooks team.

But Autodesk APS Webhooks provides a way to use Secret Token to validate and make sure the correct call is from the Webhooks service,
Check the details about Secret Token at
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/field-guide/#secret-token

Also check the workflow as:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/how-to-verify-payload-signature/

To set up the Secret Token, you can create a new one or update the existing one by the following endpoints:

- https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/tokens/tokens-POST/
- https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/tokens/tokens-me-PUT/